# How do I use the DailyMotion API?

Tags: php, api

Can anyone here help me with the integration of the DailyMotion API? I am using their SDK but to no avail, and forums are also not helping much.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question...

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried using the DailyMotion SDK. It worked very well but later on for some reason I was told not to use SDKs. So here is the PHP code to use the API using cURL.

```
define("DAILYMOTION_API_KEY", "xyzzz");
define("DAILYMOTION_API_SECRET_KEY", "abcc");
$testUser = "username";
$testPassword = "pwd";
$url = 'https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/token';
$testVideoFile = "<file location>";
$vidName = "testing video";
$vidDesc = "this is a test";
/* GET ACCESS TOKEN */
try {
$data = "grant_type=password&client_id=" . DAILYMOTION_API_KEY . "&client_secret=" .      DAILYMOTION_API_SECRET_KEY . "&username=abs&password=pwd&scope=read+write";
$curlInit = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($curlInit);
curl_close($curlInit);
$res = json_decode($output);
$accessToken = $res->access_token;
$getUploadUrl = "curl -d 'access_token=$accessToken' -G  https://api.dailymotion.com/file/upload/";
$uploadUrl = json_decode(system($getUploadUrl));
$postFileCmd = "curl -F 'file=@$testVideoFile'" . ' "' . $uploadUrl->upload_url . '"';
$postFileResponse = json_decode(system($postFileCmd));

$postVideoCmd = "curl -d 'access_token=$accessToken&url=$postFileResponse->url' https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos";

$postVideoResponse = json_decode(system($postVideoCmd));
$videoId = $postVideoResponse->id;

$publishCmd = "curl -F 'access_token=$accessToken' \
 -F 'title=$vidName' \
 -F 'published=true' \
 -F 'description=this is a test' \
 https://api.dailymotion.com/video/$videoId";

 $publishres = system($publishCmd);
 print_r($publishres);
 echo "Video is posted & published Successfully";
 } catch (Exception $e) {
 print_r($e);
 }
```

Comment: Is this code still valid? $res = json_decode($output); returns nothing for me.

Comment: yes it is valid. My scripts are running perfectly fine. make sure you using proper credentials and variables like video path location.

Comment: Add this line in script as well 
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);